# Theme Customiser not live previewing changes on pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I've been working with the Theme Customiser API lately and found that pseudo elements are not live updating using the previewer. In my project I have an image containing a transparent overlay using pseudo elements.

```
   .hero-section:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #000000;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

While this doesn't live update:

```
    // Update targeting a pseudo element.
    wp.customize( 'image_color', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newval ) {
            $('.hero-section:before').css('background', newval );
        } );
    } );
```

This does live update:

```
   // Update targeting a class.
   wp.customize( 'image_color', function( value ) {
       value.bind( function( newval ) {
           $('.hero-section').css('background', newval );
       } );
   } );
```

All settings are set using `postMessage`.

```
   $wp_customize->add_setting('image_color', array(
      'default'       => '#000000',
      'transport'     => 'postMessage',
   ) );

   $wp_customize->get_setting( 'image_color' )->transport = 'postMessage';
```

If I save changes (refresh) everything is working fine, the color is updated. How can it be that pseudo elements don't work when live updating?

Comment: AFAIK you can't target pseudo elements with jQuery - `$( ".classame:before" )` won't work.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic That's probably it, will have to use extra markup then. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: As @TheDeadMedic indicates you [can't access pseudo elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/1176359), so it is a jQuery issue. You could make use of a plugin like [JSS](https://github.com/dvtng/jss) to write a stylesheet into the page which includes `:before` or `:after` elements.